# ExactTarget - matching a SentEvent to the Sendable Data Extension that was used?

Tags: marketing-cloud

When looking at the Send Event from the SOAP API - you get all of the lists that were used to generate the send. If the send was done via a Sendable Data Extension - this is set to the All Subscribers list. Is there a way to trace the send back to the data extension that was used to generate it?

I have tried including ObjectID in the query, but it does not like that.